# Design Restful API Get manipulated data from resource

Tags: rest, api, api-design, web-api

I am new to rest, I have an entity called availableJobPositions. I want to get most Interesting job by sending a person skills. which url is good in restful:

```
api/positions/skill/most-intersting?skills[]=php&skills[]=mysql
```

or

```
api/most-intersting-job?skills[]=php&skills[]=mysql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST say that you should use http verbs for interaction with the resources. So in this case the resource is interesting-jobs, that's why  I recomend the second option, but you should use POST to pass the skill set.